# Which datatype to use?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a very basic question

Say I have 3 radio buttons on front end and I want to get the value and store in some data type. Now, at a time only one of those radio buttons can be set. What would be the most efficient way to set and get the value to know which radio button is enabled? Which datatype should I use?

Comment: Look for [ButtonGroup with .getSelection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#getSelection()) at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you "storing" it?

You could use an `enum` in your program code. But you will still probably persist it in the database as either an *ordinal* (meaning just 1, 2, 3, etc.) or string. I personally prefer string because there is less change of a value being misaligned. For example, if you re-order the enum (a simple thing to do in the code) and don't change all the values in the database, it can map incorrectly when you go to retrieve them again.

In Java, enums are complex types which can implement interfaces, so you can rely on that feature to get things like display values.

So, short answer:

- enum in code
- string in database

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swing JRadioButtons, you can associate a string with each button using setActionCommand(String) and get the selected String using ButtonGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand().

A group of radio buttons is basically like an array of Strings with a single selection.

Comment: +1 - Beat me to it. Using a `ButtonGroup` is almost definitely the expected convention.

Comment: I was concerned about using a string as there would be 3 strings associated with each of the radio buttons. In reality however, we just should need 1 'true' value for the radio button that is enabled. Isn't using a BitSet more efficient? Say if we have 100 radio options(hypothetically) would it still be a good idea to use string?

Comment: You could even use the JRadioButton instances themselves. As a general rule I would say, if you can create 100 Radio Buttons, you won't have a problem creating 100 Strings as well, so it's quite safe to use Strings.

Answer (score 0):

String will be good to use as in case of radio button only one will be active at a time so it  can be stored in a string